# iPhone 5s internet not working

Tags: iphone

Well, Monday night i went out to hangout with some friends and my iphone 5s cellular internet was working fine, midway into the night a few hours after hanging out my cellular data internet completely shut off, I usually have LTE but now not a single icon was in place of where the LTE one originally was. Is there a way to fix this? and no i havent went over my data plan. It does work on wifi as well.

Comment: Have you tried contacting your carrier?

Answer (score 0):

First, go to Settings > General > About, and wait to see if the "Update Carrier Settings?" Dialogue box appears.

Then, hard reset your phone by holding down the Home and Power button until you see the Apple logo.

If that doesn't resolve your connectivity issue:
Go to Settings > General > Reset, and tap "Reset Network Settings". Enter your passcode if you have one set.

Tap "Reset Network Settings" again. This will cause your phone to restart, and you will lose all stored Wi-Fi passwords.

However, it usually resolves problems like this. Back up your phone first if you aren't sure you remember all of your Wi-Fi passwords.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost. Go into your settings and see if cellular data is disabled. Even if it's not disabled, try turning the feature off and then on again. This can sometimes work. 
But if that doesn't work, make sure to backup all of the content on your iphone either to icloud through wifi or onto a computer with itunes installed. Then go into Settings>General>Reset and select "Reset all settings". This may take a few minutes, but when the reset is complete proceed to test your cellular data connection. (This should not erase all of your data, just reset your settings in the OS). 
If this fails, go back to Settings>General>Reset and select "Erase all content and settings". this will take a bit longer to do and will erase everything so make sure that you have a proper backup. If this doesn't fix the problem, it is most likely not a software issue and you may want to contact your nearest Apple Store to see some of your options.